# Extract media files from cache using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to download some videos from a website using `Selenium`.

Unfortunately, I can't **download** it from the source cause the video is stored in a directory with restricted access, trying to retrieve them using `urllib`, `requests` or `ffmpeg` returns a `403 Forbidden` error, even after injecting my user data to the website.

I was thinking of playing the video in its entirety and storing the **media** file from the **cache**.

Would it be a possibility? Where can I find the cache folder in a custom profile? How do I discriminate among files in the cache?

EDIT: This is what I attempted to do using `requests`

```
import requests


def main():

    s = requests.Session()

    login_page = '<<login_page>>'
    login_data = dict()
    login_data['username'] = '<<username>>'
    login_data['password'] = '<<psw>>'

    login_r = s.post(login_page)

    video_src = '<<video_src>>'

    cookies = dict(login_r.cookies) # contains the session cookie

    # static cookies for every session
    cookies['_fbp'] = 'fb.1.1630500067415.734723547'
    cookies['_ga'] = 'GA1.2.823223936.1630500067'
    cookies['_gat'] = '1'
    cookies['_gid'] = 'GA1.2.1293544716.1631011551'
    cookies['user'] = '66051'

    video_r = s.get(video_src, cookies=cookies)
    print(video_r.status_code)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The print() function returns:

> 403

This is the network tab for the video:

[image]

Comment: Does the website fetch a file with "m3u8" extension before playing the video?

Comment: It don't think so. The file extension in src is a simple `.mp4` file. It seems that the video streaming is passed through videojs library.
The network tab shows a 206 response while passing the cookies. I'm trying to emulate that using the `requests` module and will let you know if something different happens

Comment: No luck with it, request still returns `403`

Comment: share your code that you tried so far

Comment: @Sabil added to my original post

Comment: the 403 errors may be because of lack of authentication in your request... I would check out the source code of some browser plug-ins to see what they do.  I would think they probably don't deal directly with cache files.  There are also tools like Wireshark that may give you a better idea of how to craft your requests. (There are various resources there: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/13425/streaming-url/ )

Comment: Can you provided the URL that you are trying extract these videos from?

Comment: #1 Share us the url or find something similar on google #2 Is a requirement use selenium to download the video?

Comment: Can you provide the information for --  print(video_r.headers) -- to your question?

Comment: I found a solution! I'm gonna share it as soon as possible and to the best of my knowledge in the answer for future reference.
To sum it up, I got curious why I received the `403`Error, 
I then performed a scan of the network activity using a similar tool to Wireshark (as @pcalkins) suggested and noticed that the network request was able to return the desired `206` response when the request header contained as `Referer` parameter the domain of the website

Comment: As soon as I have time I'll update an answer. Unfortunately I couldn't share the website link cause it's blocked by a paywall and to my knowledge I've never encountered such kind of block in any other website.
Thanks a lot for the help and the ideas guys!

Comment: Can you share the solution please?  I have the same problem the site I'm trying to download video uses some CSRF protection

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `video_r = s.get(video_src, cookies=cookies)` Have you try to stream the response ? which send correct byte-range headers to download the video. Most websites prevent downloading the file as "one" block.

```py
with open('...', 'wb') as f:
     response = s.get(url=link, stream=True)
            
     for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=512):
         if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
             f.write(chunk)
```

You can send a head request before if you want, in that way you can create a progress bar, you will retrieve the full content length from header.

Also a 403 is commonly use by anti-bot system, may be your selenium is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You blocked because you forgot about headers.
You must use:

```
s.get('https://httpbin.org / headers', headers ={'user-agent': <The user agent value (for example: last line of your uploaded image)>})
```

or:

```
s.headers.update({'user-agent': <The user agent value (for example: last line of your uploaded image)>})
```

before sending a request